# Where can I find my Visual Studio part number?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an inventory of all of our Visual Studio installations. Microsoft has a record of a number of licenses for two versions of Pro with these part numbers: 77D-00110 and 77D-00111. I'd like to determine which is installed on each of our laptops, but I have no idea where I can find this license to determine which Pro version is which. Any idea where it can be found?

Thanks,

Chris

**UPDATE**

77D-00110 refers to: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional Edition - license & software assurance
77D-00111 refers to: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional Edition - software assurance